# C++ Wordle: Debug Window not matching Game Screen

Tags: c++, visual-c++, sfml

[Game Window to the left, Debug Window to the Right](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hry68.png)

The debug window is displaying exactly what should be happening on the game window, yet the game window is, evidently, inaccurate. I have been trying to look through the code seeing what the issue is but I can't figure it out.

[Picture of Code for Checking the Words](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FVriH.png)

[The Drawing of the Colored Rectangles that are set in checkLetters() above](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bk4UP.png)

```
void checkLetters(sf::RenderWindow& window, std::vector<textChar> text, std::string finalWord, std::vector<std::string> unicodeStorage) {

for (int i = 0; i < unicodeStorage.size(); i++) {
    sf::RectangleShape inLoopRect;
    inLoopRect.setSize(sf::Vector2f(100, 100));
    inLoopRect.setOutlineColor(sf::Color(0, 0, 0, 0));
    inLoopRect.setOutlineThickness(3);

    auto debug = 0;

    if (finalWord.find(unicodeStorage.at(i)) == std::string::npos)
        debug = -1;
    else
        debug = finalWord.find(unicodeStorage.at(i));

    std::cout << "Index in Word: " << debug << " (" << unicodeStorage.at(i) << ") " << "     Index in Loop: " << (i) % 5 << std::endl;

    if (finalWord.find(unicodeStorage.at(i)) != std::string::npos) {
        if (finalWord.find(unicodeStorage.at(i)) == (i) % 5) {
            std::cout << "GREEN for '" << unicodeStorage.at(i) << "' at " << finalWord.find(unicodeStorage.at(i)) << std::endl;
            inLoopRect.setFillColor(sf::Color(50, 150, 50, 255));

            std::cout << "VALID: " << text.at(i).POSITIONX - 15 << ", " << text.at(i).POSITIONY + 5 << "\n" << std::endl;
            inLoopRect.setPosition(text.at(i).POSITIONX - 15 + (100), text.at(i).POSITIONY + 5);
        }
        else {
            std::cout << "YELLOW for '" << unicodeStorage.at(i) << "' at " << finalWord.find(unicodeStorage.at(i)) << std::endl;
            inLoopRect.setFillColor(sf::Color(185, 185, 40, 255));
            inLoopRect.setPosition(text.at(i).POSITIONX - 15 + (100), text.at(i).POSITIONY + 5);
        }
    }
    else {
        inLoopRect.setFillColor(sf::Color(60, 60, 60, 255));
        inLoopRect.setPosition(text.at(i).POSITIONX - 15 + (100), text.at(i).POSITIONY + 5);
    }
    rect.push_back(inLoopRect);
}
```

}

Here is the actual code for the checkLetters() function. If anything else is needed, please let me know (this is all in SFML btw, if that changes anything)

Comment: What is in `std::vector<std::string> unicodeStorage`?

Comment: I push_back() every letter as I enter them into unicodeStorage